# Drop schema containing tables in HBase using Phoenix

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

How can I drop a schema that contains tables in HBase using Phoenix?

- HBase version :1.2.6
- Phoenix Version : 4.10.0-Hbase-1.2.0

I am trying to drop a schema, but I'm unable to do it. My schema consists of some tables.

I get an error that the schema is not empty. How can I drop the schema in that case? What extra do I have to do?

This is the Java code using Phoenix to drop schema from HBase:

```
Connection conn = setupDbConnection();  
statement = conn.createStatement();  
statement.executeUpdate("DROP SCHEMA "+schemaName);  
conn.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

https://phoenix.apache.org/language/#drop_schema

> Drops a schema and corresponding name-space from hbase. To enable
>   namespace mapping, see https://phoenix.apache.org/tuning.html
>
> This statement succeed only when schema doesn't hold any tables.

Is this setting configured?

```
phoenix.schema.isNamespaceMappingEnabled to true
```

Comment: yes I configured those setting in hbase-site.xml and as well as in my client program too.  But the error is that the schema/namespace is not empty.So my question is how to drop schema when it contains some tables.